# Custom SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

So I'm using EF6 and I have a simple data model. One of the entities in the data model is mapped to use stored procedures to do inserts, updates and deletes with the MapToStoredProcedures() method.

If I generate a code-based migration or script a migration, I get the code or script that contains the stored procedures. My problem is that I would like to tweak the generation of these stored procedures (I know I could just modify the generated migrations themselves after they are generated, but that's no fun).

Based on the documentation and some useful resources around Google, I have found that I should create a custom MigrationSqlGenerator descendant (to be more precise SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator in my case), then register it with the migration Configuration class.

So I have my generator:

```
public class MyGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{         
  protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
  {                      
    base.Generate(createTableOperation);
  }

  public override string GenerateProcedureBody(ICollection<DbModificationCommandTree> commandTrees, string rowsAffectedParameter, string providerManifestToken)
  {            
    return base.GenerateProcedureBody(commandTrees, rowsAffectedParameter, providerManifestToken);
  }
}
```

Then I created my initial migration for my model using Enable-Migrations and Add-Migration. Finally, I registered the generator in the Configuration class:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyCtx>
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    this.SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new MyGenerator());            
  }
  // ...
}
```

Now if I delete my initial migration but leave the Configuration class itself intact and call Add-Migration again, I can see that Generate gets called (I just added a simple file logger to the method to verify) but GenerateProcedureBody is not called. And whatever I write into that method is not applied to the insert, update and delete stored procedures either.
So I'm pretty confident that I have everything wired up correctly (the providername is OK in the app.config, and besides, the Generate method does get called, so the component should be at the right place), but I can't get the stored procedure manipulation going.

Any help is appreciated.